# How do I get XSD Schema to validate a unique element for one path above?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have an XSD schema that looks for unique values but only looks for it under one path and not unique for one level above it (look at XML file, I have the description next to the part where it should fail)

My XML Hierarchy is:

```
Root: Root
..........Targets
..................Target
..........Packages
..................Package
.........................Dependencies
......................................BuildDependency
......................................................<RelativeSandboxPath> <---HAS TO BE UNIQUE
```

XML file that SHOULD fail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <ProjectName>aabc</ProjectName>
  <ProjectVersion>1.0</ProjectVersion>
  <Targets>
    <Target>
      <TargetName>foo</TargetName>
      <CommandLine>gcc bar</CommandLine>
      <BuildEnvTypeName>none</BuildEnvTypeName>
      <RelativeOutputPath>none</RelativeOutputPath>
      <RelativeLogPath>none</RelativeLogPath>
      <Dependencies/>
    </Target>
  </Targets>
  <Packages>
    <Package>
      <Dependencies>
        <BuildDependency>
          <ProjectName>foo</ProjectName>
          <ProjectVersion>1</ProjectVersion>
          <TargetName>bar</TargetName>
          <ProjectBuild>none</ProjectBuild> 
          <RelativeSandboxPath>Unique</RelativeSandboxPath> ***has to be unique under all /Dependencies***
          <RelativeSandboxPath>Unique</RelativeSandboxPath> ***if this was here (it's not), then the XML would fail***
        </BuildDependency>
        <BuildDependency>
          <ProjectName>bar</ProjectName>
          <ProjectVersion>3</ProjectVersion>
          <TargetName>foo</TargetName>
          <ProjectBuild>3</ProjectBuild> 
          <RelativeSandboxPath>Unique</RelativeSandboxPath> ***has to be unique under all /Dependencies***
        </BuildDependency>
      </Dependencies>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Root>
```

XSD Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections />
        <Tables />
        <Sources />
      </DataSource>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="ProjectName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="ProjectVersion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Targets" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Target" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TargetName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="CommandLine" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="BuildEnvTypeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="RelativeOutputPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="RelativeLogPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Dependencies" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Packages" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Package" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="CommandLine" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="BuildEnvTypeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="PackageName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="RelativeOutputPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="RelativeLogPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="Dependencies" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="BuildDependency" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ProjectName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="ProjectVersion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="TargetName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="ProjectBuild" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="RelativeSandboxPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="PBC" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    *******HERE*********
    <xs:unique name="BuildDependency_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//BuildDependency" />
      <xs:field xpath="RelativeSandboxPath" />
    </xs:unique>
    *******HERE*********
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is exactly your problem. So just some tips:

1. According to the schema you provided there cannot occur two "RelativeSandboxPath" elements in "BuildDependenc" element. So XML example you provided will fail due this, not because of unique constraint. If there could be more than one "RelativeSandboxPath" element you should change `<xs:element name="RelativeSandboxPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>` into `<xs:element name="RelativeSandboxPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`
2. Element "NewDataSet" is not shown in your XML as well as "PBC" element it tries to reference. And it neither doesn't fit structure you presented early in your post. So I don't know what is its purpose. But if you want constrain "BuildDependency" elements you should declare this constraint at "Dependencies" element, e.g.:

   ```
   <xs:element name="Dependencies" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="BuildDependency" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                   <xs:complexType>
                       <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element name="ProjectName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                           <xs:element name="ProjectVersion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                           <xs:element name="TargetName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                           <xs:element name="ProjectBuild" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                           <xs:element name="RelativeSandboxPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                       </xs:sequence>
                   </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
       <xs:unique name="BuildDependency_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1">
           <xs:selector xpath=".//BuildDependency"/>
           <xs:field xpath="RelativeSandboxPath"/>
       </xs:unique>
   </xs:element>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your requirements very clearly. But here's a way of thinking about it: if you want every B within the same A to have a unique value for C, then in the element declaration for A, define an xs:unique constraint where the selector XPath selects B from A, and the field XPath selects C from B. For example, if every Child of a Person should have a unique firstName, then in Person define xs:unique with selector xpath="Child", field xpath="firstName".